# .htaccess hide “last modified” and “parent directory”

Tags: web-server, .htaccess

I'm trying to get my .htaccess file to list all files in the current directory, hide the 'last modified' column and also remove the link to "Parent Directory" all in the 'fancy' style.

My current file is:

```
Options +Indexes
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Great question! I had this exact same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two options you would need to use, from the [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions), are:

- `IndexOptions SuppressLastModified`
- `IndexIgnore ..`

Comment: Fantastic cheers Dave!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache? If so, this may be useful:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore

Comment: Aha great, adding this hides "last modifed":

IndexOptions +SuppressLastModified

Just need to hide the link back to the parent directory, any thoughts?